# How to prove if an only if for a equivalence relation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of the group $G$. Let $x,y \in G$ and define a relation on G by $x \equiv y$ if and only if there exists $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ such that $x = hyk$. Prove that the relation is an equivalence relation.

I proved the equivalence relation but how do I prove the "if and only if" part?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! The ''if and only if'' is used for definition purposes.

Comment: "if and only if" is the definition of relation. You don't need to prove it.

Comment: In a definition one usually just says "if", and not "if and only if". An example: A number $n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq2}$ is a *prime number*, if $p\cdot q=n$ implies that  $p=1$ or $q=1$; and not "if and only if $p\cdot q=n$ implies that  $p=1$ or $q=1$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter That's a failure of conventional definition phrasing. It _ought_ to be if and only if.

Answer (score 1):

When they say

> $x \equiv y$ if and only if there exists $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ such that $x = hyk$

then that's something they are *assuming*. The problem asks you to prove that *given this assumption*, the relation $\equiv$ fulfills the requirements to be an equivalence relation.